# Using recursion to find the smallest int an array?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

Here is my code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    
    int[] array = {5,3,1,0,4,7};
    int smallest = array[0];
    System.out.println(smallest(array,smallest));
    
    
    
}


private static int smallest(int[] array, int smallest){
    
    int count = 0;
    if(array[count] < smallest){
        smallest = array[count];
    }
    else if(array[count] == array[array.length-1]){
        return smallest;
    }
    count++;
    return smallest(array,smallest);
    
}
```

I need to use Java to find the smallest int in an array using RECURSION, I know how to use iteration to find it, but this is strictly recursion. Any help would be apperciated.. the error seems to me this line here.

--> return smallest(array,smallest);

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that one version of the variable "count" is created on every call of "smallest" and getting 0 assigned to it, so it doesn't matter you increase its value before calling "smallest" again.
Variables created inside of a function are not shared between function calls.

The problem you has is caused because "count" is always 0 and the recursion never ends, so it ends in a stack overflow error.

To solve that you have to add another parameter, "count", that will hold the iterations of the algorithm.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


int[] array = {5,3,1,0,4,7};
int smallest = array[0];
System.out.println(smallest(array,smallest,0));



}


private static int smallest(int[] array, int smallest, int count){

if(array[count] < smallest){
    smallest = array[count];
}
else if(array[count] == array[array.length-1]){
    return smallest;
}

return smallest(array,smallest,count+1);

}
```

Comment: Holy shit I literally just made that same exact change before reading your comment. I added the count variable, and it worked, but I was curious is it possible to do it without the count variable?

Comment: It would be possible to do it with a global static "count" variable defined outside main() and smallest() methods... but I do not recommend using global variables. There is a way without using a count variable, that would imply removing the first element of the "array" array before every smallest() recursive call,... but it is easier and faster to use a "count" variable.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your code enters into the `if` or `else if` blocks, it will continue to go forward and call smallest, again. Since you are passing the exact same parameters, you are getting the exact same result. **Remember count is a local variable.**

Also, I think you may want `if` instead of `else if` because if the last number is smaller, you will likely get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

When you have two numbers, you just need to compare them to find the smallest. So, if you split your array into two, find a smallest in each half, then just compare the results to find the smallest. Here is the outline of your recursion (note: I did not compile or test it):

`int getSmallest(ArrayList<Integer> numbers) {
    if (numbers.size() == 1) return numbers.get(0);
    int leftMin = getSmallest(numbers.subList(0, numbers.size()/2);
    int rightMin = getSmallest(numbers.subList(numbers.size()/2, numbers.size());
    return leftMin < rightMin ? leftMin : rightMin;
}`

If you need to use int[], you can still use the same approach, it just needs some tweaking :)